# determine the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, $a,b>0$ and consider the homomorphism of groups $f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$, given by $f(x,y)=ax-by$.

I already know that $\ker(f)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Question: What is $\ker(f)$ explicitly, is it $\ker(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\mid \exists s\in\mathbb{Z}\;\text{such that}\; (x,y)=s(b,a)\}$? I think it is not correct and I can prove $\supseteq$, but not the other inclusion.

Comment: What if $a=b=2$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\ker f&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\,|\,f(x,y)=0\}\\&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\,|\,ax=by\}.\end{align}If $a',b'\in\mathbb N$ are such that $a=a'(a,b)$ and that $b=b'(a,b)$, then $ax=by\iff a'x=b'y$ and, since $(a',b')=1$, $a'x=b'y\iff y=sa'$ and $x=sb'$ for some integer $s$. Therefore$$\ker f=\left\{(sb',sa')\,\middle|\,s\in\mathbb Z\right\}=\left\{\left(\frac{sb}{(a,b)},\frac{sa}{(a,b)}\right)\,\middle|\,s\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and translate the condition $\,ax=by\;$ with the help of *Gauß' lemma*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $a=d\bar a$, $b=d\bar b$ so that $\gcd(\bar a,\bar b)=1$.
Then $f(x,y)=(\bar ax-\bar by)d$ hence $f(x,y)=0$ if and only if $\bar ax=\bar by$.
Then $\bar a\mid y$ and $\bar b\mid x$ thus $x=n\bar b$ and $y=n\bar a$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.
Consequently, $(x,y)=(n\bar b,n\bar a)$.
Thus $$\Bbb Z\to\mathrm{Ker}(f):n\mapsto n(\bar b,\bar a)$$
gives the required isomorphism of abelian groups.